# Proof by definition of limit.

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

Using the definition of the limit, we want to prove that
$$
\lim_{z\to i} (1/z) = -i
$$

We understand that we need to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a positive number $\delta$ such that $|1/z -(-i)|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|z-i|< \delta$.

I'm having trouble here however, I don't know how to continue. I have to write $|1/z + i|$ in a way of $|z-i|$ but i can't find a way of doing that.

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$, then you have to prove $\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}\to-i$ as $(x,y)\to(0,1)$. Split up the real and imaginary parts, then you have to prove $\frac x{x^2+y^2}\to0$ and $-\frac y{x^2+y^2}\to-1$.

Comment: $-i=1/i$ hence $|1/z+i|=|1/z-1/i|=|(i-z)/(iz)|$.

Comment: May even be easier to follow if you proved the general case $\,z \to a \ne 0 \implies \frac{1}{z} \to \frac{1}{a}\,$.

Comment: @Artem , how is $-i=1/i$?

Comment: $$-i\times\frac ii = -\frac{i^2}i=-\frac{-1}i=\frac1i$$